# Slide up like Snapchat memories

Tags: android, android-fragments

As shown in gif as I slide up on the home screen in snapchat memories fragment appear. How do I approach this?

[image: Slide up snapchat]

Comment: this is bottomSheet in android

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/ try this

Comment: https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet also this

Comment: it could be another activity with shared element activity transition

Answer (score 0):

Like this example help you to create Snapchat memories
http://akcjayaprakash.blogspot.com/2016/11/accurate-geofencing-optimization-using.html

And they have Github

https://github.com/JayaprakashR-Zealot/SnapchatDashboard